# Program to connect Samsung SGH-T340G phone to Linux via USB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, device-driver, phone, archiving

I'd like connect via USB to access info and send texts on phone. But when I connect via USB, it does not show up anywhere on the PC.

**Device Specs:**

- My PC OS is Linux Mint 13 Maya, (Ubuntu based)
- My cell-phone is a Samsung, Model: [SGH-T340G](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/owners/product/SGH-T340ZKATFN) (GP)
- The phone's OS is n/a according to Samsung's web-site.
- I do not have BlueTooth capabilities on my LapTop, but do on phone.

**Requirements:**

- Connect via USB
- Access device info
- Send texts via my PC.

My phone is no "smart-phone", so are there any packages that may help me accomplish this?  If I haven't provided enough info, sorry & please ask.

Comment: The make is not as important as the OS of the phone' what is the OS?. (in general - I'm not much of a phone jockey so I can't really comment on this particular case)

Comment: You don't need any software to plug in the USB cable. But I guess you're looking for something to interact with the device, once it's plugged in. What do you want to accomplish? What features are needed? What are, maybe, nice-to-haves? What OS is your phone running (Samsung sells devices with Tizen, Bada, Android, and other OSs)? Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Izzy I have edited post.
I'm brand new to the site. If there is any other input you want to add, please do.

Comment: I've checked a little around meanwhile: there's nowhere any full specs on that device available. Without that, it will be hard to figure what software might be available, as one cannot say without having tried *with that device*. You might try [BitPim](http://www.bitpim.org/) and [Gnokii](http://gnokii.org/) (both available in Ubuntu repos), but no guarantees that any of them supports your device (though hope's there, at least with Gnokii in basic AT mode).

Comment: Yeah, I've done the same. I've tried Gnokii, but didn't work. Not sure if I set it to "AT" though.  I'll give it a try and let everyone know. Thanks again @Izzy

Comment: @NiVeK1776 did you ever come around to this?

Comment: please connect the mobile to your usb, wait 5 seconds then issue the command "lsusb" and post the output in your question.